# Is it possible to open a link into Safari from inside Websheet.app

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I'd like to know if it is possible, on the iPhone, to open a link into Safari from inside the Websheet app which is displayed when one tries to access a captive network.
Any client-side solution would do the trick (custom protocol, javascript, whatever).

The scenario would be as follow:

1. the user joins the captive network
2. the Websheet pops in, and the user can authenticate
3. After that, the user is redirected to a custom URL, but in **Safari**

Thanks a lot

Comment: safari is a system application in iphone when we called safari app it will open newly in iphone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can open any link in Mobile Safari from inside your application. Simply do this

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString: launchUrl]
```

launchUrl is the url (in string format) you want to open in safari.

Comment: Thanks, but I am not in any native ios app. I would like to open Safari from the Websheet.app, ie the popup which is displayed when you connect to a wifi which require credentials through a webform (like in Starbucks for example).

Comment: Sorry my friend, I am afraid you can't to that. Apple doesn't allow that